# How to position a set in Raphael SVG?

Tags: javascript, css, text, svg, raphael

I am trying to position a set of elements including text, path and circle in raphael. Is there a way to position the entire set in the svg? The SVG itself covers the entire height and width of the window and **the set needs to be positioned in the center of the SVG.**
The code is as follows:

```
var r = Raphael("holder", windowWidth, windowHeight);

    var set = r.set(
    (r.text(100,250,"ab").attr({...})),
    (r.text(295,250,"c").attr({..})),
    (r.path("M400,217L400,317").attr({...})),
    (r.circle(190, 290, 13).attr({...})));

    for (var i=0; i<set.length; i++) {
      set[i].node.setAttribute("class", "set");
    }
```

I've added the class in case the set could be manipulated using css, but I havent found any method to do so.
Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a transform on a set, like http://jsbin.com/EzUFiD/1/edit?html,js,output (fiddle isn't working for me)

```
var svgWidth = 600; 
var svgHeight = 600;
var r = Raphael("holder", svgWidth, svgHeight);


var set = r.set(
  (r.text(50,50,"ab")),
  (r.text(50,60,"c")),
  (r.path("M100,17L40,31")),
  (r.circle(80, 80, 13))
);

var bbox = set.getBBox();  //find surrounding rect of the set

var posx = svgWidth / 2 - bbox.width / 2 - bbox.x;  // find new pos depending on where it is initially
var posy = svgHeight / 2 - bbox.height / 2 - bbox.y;


set.transform('t' + posx + ',' + posy);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I ended up positioning the elements individually as an animation which was required would not fall into the set.

Comment: Depends what you mean, you can animate a set ok, here's an updated example... http://jsbin.com/EzUFiD/3/  set.animate({transform: "t100,100"}, 1000);